# how to get a total of an array each time the user add something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

i have a book shop that has books, and the user can add those books into cart, then the total price of those books is shown in the cart, each time he add something new, the state adds that number, the probelm was the user could spam one item into the array, so i wanted to limit the number to one rare item, i managed to limit the shown books, but i didn't know how to get the total price afterwards

below is what i tried:

```
function BookCard({
  name,
  image,
  price,
  author,
  language,
  description,
  email,
  exchangeable,
  lendable,
  year,
  user,
}) {

  const { setItems, setTotalPrice, items } = useContext(context);

  function addToCart() {
    setItems((prev) => {
      const filteredItems = prev.filter((item) => {
        const oldName = item.name;
        return name !== oldName;
      });

      return [...filteredItems, { name: name, price: price }];
    });

    setTotalPrice((prevPrice) => {
      const [newPrice] = items.slice(-1);

      if (newPrice && newPrice.price !== price) return prevPrice + price;
      else return price;
    });
  }
```

my context wrapper looks like this

```
function CartContext({ children }) {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [currentPrice, setCurrentPrice] = useState(0);

  const contextValue = {
    items: cartItems,
    totalPrice: currentPrice,
    setTotalPrice: setCurrentPrice,
    setItems: setCartItems,
  };
  return <context.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</context.Provider>;
}
```

what i want:

only to add rare items, and get the total price of those items, thanks in advance

Comment: Don't do unnecessary `setTotalPrice`. It is enough to have cart items in state. Rest can be calculated (and memoized if necessary). Like `const totalPrice = getTotalPrice(items)` inside of `CartContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have an issue in the `setTotalPrice` function, the rest looks fine:

```
    setTotalPrice((currentPrice) => {
      // this ensures you won't double-add the price to the existing total
      if (items.find((item) => item.name === name)) {
        return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
          return acc + item.price;
        }, 0);
      }
      // and if the item is not in the array, then add the price
      return price + currentPrice;
    });
```

You would do a similar thing when removing from cart. Example:

```
    removeFromCart: (name) => {
      setCartItems((prev) => {
        return prev.filter((item) => item.name !== name);
      });
      setCurrentPrice((currentPrice) => {
        return (
          currentPrice - cartItems.find((item) => item.name === name).price
        );
      });
    }
```